# WIF 4.5 and partial-trust environments

Tags: wcf, wif, full-trust, partial-trust

Is WIF 4.5 supported in a partial-trust environment?  I have a WCF service that uses it and when deployed to a medium-trust environment the following error is occurring:

An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for system.identityModel: Attempt by method 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.ApplyInstanceAttributes(System.Object)' to access method 'System.IdentityModel.Configuration.IdentityConfigurationElement.get_ApplicationService()' failed.

Answer (score 0):

No WIF only runs in full trust.